Check the existence of records in the elastic search vector store
I have such entries in my elasticsearch index:

It's unstructured data, in this case the content of a PDF that was split into chunks, then a LangChain document was created for each chunk and pushed to the index as a different vector.
I faced the issue that each time I loaded the pdf and pushed it to the index, new entries were pushed (with the same content). The code that is used for that purpose is:
def push_to_elasticsearch(es_index_name,embeddings,docs):

elastic_vector_search = ElasticsearchStore(
    # es_cloud_id=es_cloud_id,
    # es_endpoint=es_endpoint,
    # es_apikey=es_apikey,

    index_name=es_index_name,
    # docs=docs,
    embedding=embeddings,
    es_connection=es_connection
)

docs_ids = [doc.metadata["hash_id"] for doc in docs]
# # print("---------------------------------------------------------->>>>>>>>>>", docs_ids)
vector_exists_dict = check_vectors_exist_by_hash_id(es_index_name, docs_ids)
print("---------------------------------------------------------->>>>>>>>>>", vector_exists_dict)
idempotency_docs = [doc for doc in docs if not vector_exists_dict.get(doc.metadata["hash_id"], False)]
# idempotency_docs = [doc for doc in docs if not vector_exists_dict.get(calculate_content_hash(doc.page_content), False)]

print('Len of docs:', len(docs))
print('Len of idempotency_docs:', len(idempotency_docs))

elastic_vector_search.add_documents(documents=docs)

db = ElasticsearchStore.from_documents(
    docs,
    embeddings,
    es_connection=es_connection,
    index_name=es_index_name,
)

return db

In order to check the existence of vectors before pushing them, I guess I couldn't use the existing _id field (since it's not pushed yet), so I added a new hash_id field in the metadata column (based on hash content), and I want to use it for searching the index before pushing. I still don't know how exactly to implement it. I thought about this implementation:
def check_vectors_exist_by_hash_id(index_name, docs_hash_ids):
"""
Check if vectors exist for a list of document IDs.

Args:
    doc_ids (list): List of document IDs to check.

Returns:
    dict: A dictionary where keys are document IDs and values are boolean (True if vector exists, False otherwise).
"""
vector_exists_dict = {}
try:
    # Fetch documents by IDs
    responses = es_connection.mget(index=index_name, body={"hash_ids": docs_hash_ids})
    for response in responses["docs"]:
        doc_id = response["hash_id"]
        vector_exists_dict[doc_id] = "embedding" in response["_source"]
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error checking vector existence for doc_ids: {e}")

return vector_exists_dict

But haven't figured out yet how to filter by these hash_ids!

I asked my question in one of the GenAI chatbots (The Copilot of Microsoft Edge), I had to ask more than one prompt and keep improving it till reaching the final result, which is:
def check_vectors_exist_by_hash_id(index_name, docs_hash_ids):
"""
Check if vectors exist for a list of document IDs.

Args:
    doc_ids (list): List of document IDs to check.

Returns:
    dict: A dictionary where keys are document IDs and values are boolean (True if vector exists, False otherwise).
"""
# vector_exists_dict = {}
# try:
#     # Fetch documents by IDs
#     responses = es_connection.mget(index=index_name, body={"_ids": docs_ids})
#     for response in responses["docs"]:
#         doc_id = response["_id"]
#         vector_exists_dict[doc_id] = "embedding" in response["_source"]
# except Exception as e:
#     print(f"Error checking vector existence for doc_ids: {e}")

# return vector_exists_dict

vector_exists_dict = {}
try:
    # Initialize a scroll search
    query = {"query": {"terms": {"metadata.hash_id": docs_hash_ids}}}
    response = es_connection.search(index=index_name, body=query, _source=False, scroll="1m")

    # Process initial hits
    for hit in response["hits"]["hits"]:
        doc_hash_id = hit["_source"]["metadata"]["hash_id"]
        vector_exists_dict[doc_hash_id] = True

    # Scroll through additional pages
    while True:
        scroll_id = response["_scroll_id"]
        response = es_connection.scroll(scroll_id=scroll_id, scroll="1m")
        if not response["hits"]["hits"]:
            break  # No more hits

        for hit in response["hits"]["hits"]:
            doc_hash_id = hit["_source"]["metadata"]["hash_id"]
            vector_exists_dict[doc_hash_id] = True

except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error checking vector existence for hash IDs: {e}")

# Mark missing vectors as False
for doc_hash_id in docs_hash_ids:
    if doc_hash_id not in vector_exists_dict:
        vector_exists_dict[doc_hash_id] = False

return vector_exists_dict

